# Exit code from with Ruby + rest client

Tags: ruby

I learning ruby and playing it with restsclient I have following test the code and I'm expecting that to return 1/false. I can't seem to make it work.

```
n@lap-jta102:~/tsamcode$ ./get.rb
n@lap-jta102:~/tsamcode$ echo $?
0 

#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rest_client'
require 'json'

begin
response = RestClient.get("https://admin:admin@172.16.210.10/isam/host_records/187.0.0.1/hostnames", :content_type => :json, :accept => :json)
return true if response.code == 200
rescue => e
return false unless response != 200
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`$?` is not set by `return`, but by [`exit`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-exit). In fact, your `return` doesn't even do what you think. Try just this:

```
# one-returner.rb
return 1

$ ruby one-returner.rb
one-returner.rb:1:in `<main>': unexpected return (LocalJumpError)
```

The reason you're not getting an error in your program is the fact that you blanket-rescue this error when raised by `return true` (since you have an unrestricted `rescue`, which is a bad practice for exactly this reason, it can catch a wrong thing and leave you puzzled), and `return false` never executes (and thus never raises an error) due to `unless`.

Comment: Thank you  for the answer. I found out about exit & exit!. I modified the it now  the code that it after the rescue it will exit! and seems doing that I expected, but I guess not the way to do it.